# Problema no menu de tabs

Tags: javascript, css

O problema é o seguinte: O usuário clica no menu ele abre normalmente, só que quando o usuário vai interagir com ele, ele fecha mas só poderia fechar se clicasse no menu referido ou fora dele.

```
<div class="navegacao">
    <span class="nav-um" tabindex="1">X</span>
    <span class="nav-dois" tabindex="1">Y</span>
    <span class="nav-tres" tabindex="1">Z</span>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="conteudo-um same">Conteúdo do elemento UM</div>
        <div class="conteudo-dois same">Conteúdo do elemento DOIS</div>
        <div class="conteudo-tres same">Conteúdo do elemento TRÊS</div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navegacao {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.navegacao span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navegacao span:hover,
.navegacao span:active,
.navegacao span:focus {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.nav-um:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um,
.nav-um:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-um {
    display: block;
}
.nav-dois:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-dois,
.nav-dois:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-dois {
    display: block;
}
.nav-tres:focus ~ .conteudo .conteudo-tres,
.nav-tres:active ~ .conteudo .conteudo-tres {
    display: block;
}

.conteudo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
.same {
    display:none;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Não cries perguntas duplicadas @mayron2017 . Primeiro pela razão de ser uma pergunta duplicada e segundo porque neste caso já tens resposta lá do outro lado, só precisava de ajustes, mas caso não tivesse irias estar a arrastar o problema por todos os lados até chegar ao ponto de se estar a responder a um problema fragmentado em várias questões quando não há a necessidade disso.

Comment: ta legal, desculpa